# Function returning only FALSE

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have a php function.

```
                if ( $this->input->post('email') == $this->_email($this->input->post('email')) )
            {
                $this->_data['error'] = 'Email exist!';
                return $this->load->view('login/template_view', $this->_data);
            }
```

My function returning only FALSE, even if equality is true. I use debug to see if my function can returning TRUE.

```
bool(false) string(14) "alex@yahoo.com" object(stdClass)#25 (1) { ["email"]=> string(14) "alex@yahoo.com" }
```

I have 2 strings, first is returning alex@yahoo.com, and 2nd string is returning alex@yahoo.com... but if condition still returning FALSE.

What is wrong in my function?

Debug:

```
                var_dump($this->input->post('email'));
                var_dump($this->_email($this->input->post('email')));
                die();
```

Comment: `$this->email()` returns an `stdClass`, not a `string`...This is not going to be equal at all. Your object contains a member `email`, this is what you should compare to your first string.

Comment: oh, you right. but how i can extract the email [string] from the object? i am beginer with codeigniter. if you can explain me i realy apreciate

Comment: Also, just `$this->load->view('login/template_view', $this->_data);` without `return`.

Comment: what is this `$this->_email($this->input->post('email'))`

Comment: _email is a function, but now my code works. thx you all for help

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing a string to an object. In order for your comparison to work, you need to compare the string against the `email` property of the object. You can access a object property by using `->` or by using a method.

You can read more about PHP objects [here](http://php.net/manual/pl/language.types.object.php) and [here](http://php.net/manual/pl/language.oop5.php).

In order for your code to work, replace:

```
if ( $this->input->post('email') == $this->_email($this->input->post('email')) )
```

with

```
if ( $this->input->post('email') == $this->_email($this->input->post('email'))->email )
```